# How to type event.target properly?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Whenever I use TypeScript, the thing which annoys me the most is, that `event.target` is always `EventTarget | null`. First of all, I would like to know under which circumstances target is null because I never came across this and also:

Is there a way to type `event.target` so that it is bound to the correct element type already?

Comment: the type depends on the event, which depend on the react component. So the type should be related to these. For example `event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>` for a mouse event on a button

Comment: I have the feeling this doesn't concern React but vanilla TS. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes it does @whygee - even tho ultimately it bothers me in vue templates but that's a different issue